# Java NIO 2 - deleting folder progress - Error occurs if window explorer is opening

Tags: java

I wrote a program for deleting a folder with all of its sub folders and files using Java NIO 2 features. The program run smoothly in case NO Window explorer is opened. But it will raises an error when Window explorer is opened(i.e. The deleting folder is "E:\Error" and i stayed at "E:"). Here is the structure of testing folder:

```
"E:\Error\Error0\Error1\Error2\Error3\Error4\Error5\Error6\Error7\Error8\Error9"
```

There are two file : "Text.txt" and "Text2.txt" in the "Error2" folder.

This is my class:

```
public class FileVisitorForTest extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
@Override
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(dir);
    Files.delete(dir);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    Files.delete(file);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path targetFolder = Paths.get("E:\\Error");
    Files.walkFileTree(targetFolder, new FileVisitorForTest());
}
}
```

The error show in console when i run program with window file explorer is opening:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: E:\Error\Error0\Error1
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:265)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1077)
at nio.FileVisitorForTest.postVisitDirectory(FileVisitorForTest.java:13)
at nio.FileVisitorForTest.postVisitDirectory(FileVisitorForTest.java:10)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:224)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:199)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:199)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:69)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2600)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2633)
at nio.FileVisitorForTest.main(FileVisitorForTest.java:25)
```

Please help me to understand this circumstance. Thank you all!

Ps: My OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

Update: This bug can be overcome by adding a Thread in the postVisitDirectory() method like this:

```
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
    Files.delete(dir);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

But i still don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

A folder can not be deleted when it is still open in an explorer window. Its a Windows thing, not a Java thing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment, but in this case i didn't open the Drive that contains the deleting folder. The folder is in drive E: but i open Window file explorer on drive C: .

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file is locked by another process.

File file = new File("some_file.txt");
System.out.println(file.canWrite());

Comment: Thanks for your answer but iam sure the file was not locked by any process because i didn't open any content in the deleting folder.

Comment: Hey I run your code, and was only able to recreate your case when a process was holding lock for any of the text files (notepad). Can you please double check, that they are not in use before the deletion happens ( try to rename them or something )

Comment: I double checked by changing the file name of txt file, and this bug still occur (In case i don't use Thread.sleep() in the postVisitDirectory() method).

Comment: OK, since the thread sleep solves the problem, I guess its related to the Windows File system's performance( its slow by default ). So when you call "Files.delete(path)" it takes some time for the OS to delete the directory and happens only for directory with files in it, which slows down the process even more. So I would suggest that your previous delete operations is locking the file. Can you tell me your hard drive specifications

Comment: Ok, my "E:" hard drive have 295 GB free out of 299 GB, it uses NTFS file system. My "C:" also have 101 GB free storage. My computer is fast because it uses i7 CPU and have 16gb ram. One thing i mention that even though i don't use the Thread.sleep() method, the bug will NEVER happens if i closed all Window explorer.

Comment: Very interesting problem.. Some people say that windows thumbnails are sometimes generated slowly and the windows explorer is accessing them ( they are hidden system file in each folder ), try disabling them (Folder options ->  View : Always show icons, never thumbnails - thick.

Comment: Unfortunately the method that you mention above didn't help. Anyway i don't think that is a good solution, because i want my program to run fine without any OS system configuration. I will find another way, thank you.